# How create an input box having a + and - button in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

How I can create an input box having a + and - button. Clicking upon which user can change the quantity of product selected, like this screen [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGCwm.png)

[image]

i know this question was here before but its not ionic3 and the answer its not work because all the values will be increased or decresed <- this question was added there but no one answer

Comment: so what is the issue - creating template for it or the controller logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I created this one for you, modify styles and functionality as needed!
>
> **CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-food-cart)

Your **`component.ts`** can be something like below

```
  constructor() {
    this.shop = this.shop.map(food => {
      food['qty'] = 0;
      return food;
    });
  }

  incrementQty(index: number) {
    this.shop[index].qty += 1;
  }

  decrementQty(index: number) {
    this.shop[index].qty -= 1;
  }
```

and your **`component.html`** can look something like below

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let food of shop;let i = index">
        <ion-card-header>
      <ion-title>
        {{i+1}}. {{food.name.first}} {{food.name.last}}
      </ion-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Total Price &nbsp;&nbsp;
        {{food.qty}} Units x ${{food.price}} = 
        ${{food.qty*food.price}}
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="incrementQty(i)" item-right></ion-icon>
            <ion-input type="number" min="1" [value]="food.qty" [(ngModel)]="food.qty"></ion-input>
            <ion-icon name="remove-circle" (click)="decrementQty(i)" item-right></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

**Hope this is helpful! Happy coding**